# How to terminate the script started with subprocess.Popen() based on specific condition

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am starting a Python script called `test.py` from the main script called `main.py`.
In the `test.py` I am tracking some machine learning metrics. When these metrics reach a certain threshold, I want to terminate the subprocess in which the `test.py` was started.

Is there a possibility to achieve this in Python if I have started this script by using:
`proc = subprocess.Popen("python test.py", shell=True)`

I haven't found anything in the documentation which would allow me to trigger this event on my own.

Comment: `proc.terminate()`? It is not elegant: I would use `proc.communicate` so you have a graceful shutdown.

Comment: I know that you can terminate it with `proc.terminate()` but how can I know **when** to do that? I am talking about triggering some event before the script has finished executing and when that event is triggered to forcefully terminate the process.

Comment: I also want to be able to send that event from the script which was run inside of the `Popen` process.

Comment: You should be better using `multiprocessing`. `subprocess` buffering issues are a nightmare.

Comment: `subprocess.run` and `p.communicate()` support a `timeout` keyword which let you shut them down when enough time has passed. But running Python as a subprocess of itself is often an antipattern.

Comment: As an aside, the `shell=True` is easy to avoid, and you probably should. See further [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Comment: Can you modify `test.py`? Do you need a portable solution or Linux-only is OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**
The easiest way to perform this is to pass the termination condition as a parameter to `test.py`.

Otherwise, you can use printing and reading from `stdout` and `stdin` If you want to preserve the output and still use Popen, see below. As an example, consider a simple `test.py` that calculates (in a very inefficient way) some primes:

**test.py**

```
import time

primes = [2, 3]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for p in primes:
        print(p, flush=True)

    i = 5
    while True:
        for p in primes:
            if i % p == 0:
                break
        if i % p:
            primes.append(i)
            print(i, flush=True)
        i += 2
        time.sleep(.005)
```

You can read the output and choose to terminate the process when you achieve the desired output. As an example, I want to get primes up to `1000`.

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen("python test.py",
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True,
                        shell=True, text=True)
must_stop = False
primes = []
while proc.poll() is None:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if line:
        new_prime = int(line)
        primes.append(new_prime)
        if  new_prime > 1000:
            print("Threshold achieved", line)
            proc.terminate()
        else:
            print("new prime:", new_prime)
print(primes)
```

please notice that since there is a delay in the processing and communication, you might get one or two more primes than desired. If you want to avoid that, you'd need bi-directional communication and `test.py` would be more complicated. If you want to see the output of `test.py` on screen, you can print it and then somehow parse it and check if the condition is fulfilled. Other options include using `os.mkfifo` (Linux only, not very difficult), which provides an easy communication path between two processes:

**`os.mkinfo` version**

**test.py**

```py
import time
import sys

primes = [2, 3]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    outfile = sys.stdout
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        try:
            outfile = open(sys.argv[1], "w")
        except:
            print("Could not open file")
    for p in primes:
        print(p, file=outfile, flush=True)
    i = 5
    while True:
        for p in primes:
            if i % p == 0:
                break
        if i % p:
            primes.append(i)
            print("This will be printed to screen:", i, flush=True)
            print(i, file=outfile, flush=True) # this will go to the main process
        i += 2
        time.sleep(.005)
```

**main file**

```
import subprocess
import os
import tempfile


tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
filename = os.path.join(tmpdir, 'fifo')  # Temporary filename
os.mkfifo(filename)  # Create FIFO
proc = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "test.py", filename], shell=False)
with open(filename, 'rt', 1) as fifo:
    primes = []
    while proc.poll() is None:
        line = fifo.readline()
        if line:
            new_prime = int(line)
            primes.append(new_prime)
            if new_prime > 1000:
                print("Threshold achieved", line)
                proc.terminate()
            else:
                print("new prime:", new_prime)
    print(primes)

    pass

os.remove(filename)
os.rmdir(tmpdir)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do that without collecting the `stdout`? What if inside of that script I have some prints that should be displayed as the console output when I run `python main.py`?

Comment: Well... you can use stderr. Is that OK for you? If you are bound to use `Popen` the options are limited.

Comment: Tbh the only reason I used `Popen` is that it allows me to start a script from the `main.py` and pass arguments to the argument parser (which is inside that script which I wish to run)